# What could cause total, catastrophic file/data loss in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, c++, file, android-ndk

I have an Android app using the NDK.  I am storing/saving files just using fopen/etc in C++.  I use this Java function to get the storage location location and pass it to C++:

```
private void SetFilePath()
{
    //String storagePath=getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    String storagePath=null;
    String cachePath=getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();

    // SDCARD
    try
    {
        String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(storageState)) storagePath=getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.v(IDS.LOG,"No permission to access external storage, missing android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    }
    if (storagePath==null) storagePath=getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    SetFilePathNative(storagePath, cachePath);
    mStorageDir = storagePath;
}
```

This is the function I use in C++ to write files:

```
bool WriteFile(char *theFilename, char *theDataPtr, int theLen)
{
    FILE* aFile=fopen(theFilename,"w+");
    if(!aFile) return false;
    fclose(aFile);
    aFile=fopen(theFilename,"w+b");
    if(!aFile) return false;
    if (aFile)
    {
        fwrite(theDataPtr, 1, theLen,aFile);
        fclose(aFile);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What is happening to some of my users (and it's fairly rare), is, they will run the app and everything will be okay for a few hours or days or some period of time.  Then, suddenly, one day they will open the app and everything will be gone-- everything will be completely wiped and the storage path retrieved by the function above will be completely empty.

I do not know if the returned path is CHANGING so that it points to a new place, or if the data is actually being wiped, but for whatever reason, it acts as if the user completely uninstalled the app.

Is there anything about the above code that looks wrong?  Can anyone suggest a reason this might be happening?

Comment: you should write to a temporary file then swap the temporary file with the target file. If your application crashes, the phone battery dies, the OS kills your app due to lack of memory etc. whilst the file is being written you could end up with an incomplete file

Comment: It could also have something to do with faulty Android auto-backups.

Comment: Alan: Hi-- the files are definitely being written.  There's several files AND folders (if you want to see the specific structure, the App is Chuzzle 2, free on Google play).  When this event happens, the entire thing is wiped-- every settings file, every folder for user profiles, literally nothing survives (I've given players special builds that upload a zip of their data to my server at intervals).  It looks like the app is uninstalled and reinstalled, but it isn't.  Gavin: I'll look into that.  It's rare enough that it must be something esoteric.

Comment: Do you know manufacturer and device? Some manufactures include clean-up apps into their system (e.g by move it's data into the cloud). May be this system app is buggy and does not recognize your files as they are created via NDK?

Comment: It's a broad spread-- doesn't seem to be one device in particular.  It's hard to get information out of end-users, but I believe all of them have an external SD card equipped, but are not removing it or changing anything when the data loss happens.

I am mainly concerned that my SetFilePath storagePath is either being created in a cache area (people having data for a time, then getting it wiped sounds like /temp behavior to me!) or that storagePath is getting a different path sometimes, due to something happening.